# apex:repeat var not getting recognized inside button

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, repeat, oncomplete

I have this button inside an apex repeat that it's iterating over a list from my extension controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Visit_Report__c" extensions="AddTopicsController" showHeader="false">
        <head>
            <script>
                function openTask(topic, valid){
                    if(valid == "true"){
                        window.open("/00T/e?retURL=/apex/VF_ForceClose&tsk5=" + topic, "Popup", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1");
                    }
                }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
            <apex:repeat value="{!topicsList}" var="topic">
                <apex:commandButton value="New Action" action="{!checkErrors}" rerender="theBlock" oncomplete="openTask('{!topic.Title__c}', '{!isValid}')"/>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

But it does not recognize the loop's variable. It says "Unknown property 'Visit_Report__cStandardController.topic'". I figured out it has to do with oncomplete but i'm not being able to understand why this happens.

Thank you!

Edit Controller code:

```
public class AddTopicsController {

    public List<Topic__c> topicsList {get;set;}
    public Visit_Report__c visit_report {get;set;}
    public boolean isValid {get;set;}

    public AddTopicsController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        visit_report = (Visit_Report__c) stdController.getRecord();
        topicsList = [Select id, Title__c, Description__c, Visit_Report__c From Topic__c Where Visit_Report__c = :visit_report.Id];
        isValid = false;
    }
    public Pagereference checkErrors(){
        isValid = false;
        boolean error = false;
        if(!error){
            isValid = true;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Edit 2: I found a workaround for this "bug", it involves transfering every action related to the topic variable to an action support element. solution:

```
<apex:commandButton value="New Action" reRender="theBlock" >
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick"  action="{!checkErrors}" oncomplete="openTask('{!topic.Title__c}', '{!isValid}')" reRender="theBlock"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? And could you also post the controller code?

Comment: Do you have a getter method within your controller thats defined as "topic"?

Comment: My controller code is just a booolean set to true for test purposes. What i'm trying to do is to open a window on click with those parameters. but with onclick the controller does not update on time to set my parameters true values. So i'm forced to use oncomplete. But using this it does not recognize my loop variable.

Comment: No getter method. Topic is suppose to be my loop variable. I have a {get;set;} on my list.

Comment: Paste your controller code to your question so we can help.

Comment: added my controller code to the post

Comment: Would it be possible to modify your var to use single character "t" and re-test?

Comment: Yeah same error. Doesn't recognize it as the loop variable. "Unknown property 'Visit_Report__cStandardController.t'".

Comment: In `openTask('{!topic.Topic__c}', '{!isValid}')`, you are passing `Topic__c`. Your repeat has the list of `Topic__c`. Are you trying to pass the ID of the record? Or the whole record?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo in the post, updated the method call. it's supposed to be `openTask('{!t.Title__c}', '{!isValid}')`

Comment: My question remains the same. What are you trying to pass to the `openTask` javascript function? I understood the second boolean parameter. What is the first parameter you are trying to pass? Is it an ID of the record? Or a complete record?

Comment: It's a text field. As i said i'm trying to open a window on click, and i want to pass the title__c as parameter in that window's url.

Comment: Updated my page code.

Comment: Added an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48936/discussion-between-shailesh-patil-and-marco-galvao).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `apex:commandButton` is not recognising the repeat variable. I would suggest you to use the `apex:input type="button"`
instead if you can.

```
<input type="button" oncomplete="openTask('{!topic.Title__c}', '{!isValid}')" value=" click here " class="btn"/>
```

You also have to write another actionSupport method which will execute your action method in the controller. 
I am not sure if it has any other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a Limitation in oncomplete which does not accept any Page side variables.

Since **checkErrors** is already a pagereference method, you can pass the parameters using  to controller and perform the action done in **openTask** JS Method

Thanks

Comment: This solution does not work in this case unfortunately :s i need to have access to that specific topic object that is assigned to that specific button. i found a solution and will post it. thank you very much for your input!